# How to set width of bibliography?

Tags: bibtex

For some references, the text extends beyond the margin of the page. How do I set it up so that this does not happen?

Comment: the width is set but you may have text that is difficult to set, you could try setting the bibliography `\sloppy` or `\raggedright` and if you have loong URL make sure they are marked as `\url{http........}` so that they can break at `/` and wrap over the lines. As you have shown no example it is hard to give specific suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... without seeing your code, it is odd to suggest, anyhow, try with `\begin{sloppypar}...\end{sloppypar}`